# How can I set the value of an attribute based on the environment I am in in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

When I push my updates to the chef server, my updates first get pushed to our development node and then I eventually merge them to the production node.

I have two attributes that set to a URL for a database, however, the value of the attributes are different based on whether I am on the development node or the production node.

How can set my attributes so it sets the value of the attribute based on what environment it is in?

Here is what I have:

```
default['test_cookbook']['Development']['URL]='jdbc:mysql://exampleDB1.com'
default['test_cookbook']['Production']['URL]='jdbc:mysql://exampleDB2.com'
```

Ideally instead of "Production" and Development, I would want some chef resource like "node.chef_environment" that will check the environment and decide what URL to use based on the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your attributes file:

```
default['test_cookbook']['Development']['URL']='jdbc:mysql://exampleDB1.com'
default['test_cookbook']['Production']['URL']='jdbc:mysql://exampleDB2.com'
```

Then at the top of your recipe pull the node attributes for the cookbook into a ruby variable and use that:

```
attributes = node['test_cookbook'][node.chef_environment]

remote_file attributes['download_location'] do
  source attributes['URL']
end

template attributes['config_file'] do
  source "myapp.conf.erb"
  variables({ attributes: attributes })
end
```

There's also an elegant way to do this via PolicyFiles using 'hoisting' where `policy_group` replaces `chef_environment` and is the recommended way going forwards:

https://docs.chef.io/release_notes_client/#policyfile-hoisting

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, Chef attributes *should not be* named after the environment in which they will be used. Environment agnostic attribute like below is preferred:

```ruby
default['test_cookbook']['jdbc_url']
```

**TL;DR**

You could achieve what you want through an attributes file. The idea is to set the attributes based on the `node.chef_environment`.

Example `test_cookbook/attributes/default.rb`:

```ruby
default['test_cookbook']['jdbc_url'] = case node.chef_environment
  when 'development'
    'jdbc:mysql://exampleDB1.com'
  when 'production'
    'jdbc:mysql://exampleDB2.com'
  end
```

**However...**

The value of this variable can be set per Chef Environment by editing the environment with `knife environment edit` or by editing the `.json` file for that environment.

This method should be preferred as the JDBC URL can be changed per environment without having to modify the cookbook. *Cookbook modifications are like code change* - involving branching, version bumping and associated `README.md` and `CHANGELOG.md` updates, code reviews and merging. This will then cascade down to using the "new" cookbook versions during deployments.

*All this for a value change!* Not preferred.

Example `development` Chef environment:

```json
  "default_attributes": {
    "test_cookbook": {
      "jdbc_url": "jdbc:mysql://exampleDB1.com"
    }
  },
```

Example `production` Chef environment:

```json
  "default_attributes": {
    "test_cookbook": {
      "jdbc_url": "jdbc:mysql://exampleDB2.com"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Would I make these additions to ".json" files that already exist or create a new one for each environment? Where do I tell chef to use the json files?

Comment: I hope you do have "development" and "production" environments to which your nodes are attached. You can do `knife environment edit development` and add the attributes. Same for "production".