# Chef:Setting node variable according to environment

Tags: chef-infra

In current project we have created various default attribute and these attribute are environment dependent.

```
For ex :default["RecpieName]["LinkServer"] .
```

This attribute value get changed as per environment.
So I am not sure how we define attribute so that same attribute can be used by all environment.

I am thinking of writing if env is dev then set this value and envirnoment is uat then another value.
I want to know the best practice  while designing such solution

Comment: I have answered something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700940/13968097), please see if it helps. The longer part of the answer might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways of setting attributes per environment, one is conditionally at the [cookbook](https://docs.chef.io/attributes/) level (by checking `node.chef_environment`), and the second is unconditionally at the [environment](https://docs.chef.io/environments/#environment-attributes) level.

you can even combine between the two, just be aware of [attribute precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes/#attribute-precedence).

from your question, it seems that you need to set the attributes at the chef environment.